# Display problem - multiple article HTML tags in same owl-item

Tags: javascript, html, prestashop, owl-carousel, prestashop-1.7

I created a store with version 1.7 of Prestashop with the Shopmy - The MultiStore template and I have a very bad problem with my owl-carousel because there are three `<article>...</article>` in the same `owl-item, I don't understand why..

When I create a new project with the same Prestashop version and with this template, there is no problem but I can't use it because there are many data in my store, I don't want to start over.

To better understand the problem, here is the code :

[image: 3 article tags in the same owl-item]

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: why are you wrapping the items in a `<strong>` tag??

Comment: good question .. it is Prestashop who adds this tag

Comment: i dont think so...it isn`t it added in the first owl-item..

Comment: I have not added anything, where can I check?

Comment: well, thats what you have to find out...I cant look into what youve done only by picture