# Display problem - Prestashop 1.7.8. multiple article HTML tags in same owl-item

Tags: nested, prestashop, owl-carousel, article

Hello I have problem widh Prestashop.

I created a store with Prestashop 1.7.8.7, I used "ebusiness" theme of Prestahero.
I have a problem with my owl-carousel because there are two products in the same tag ... in the same `owl-item.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJE42.png)

I also show the code where you can see two nested  elements each inside a  tag and I don't understand what is the source.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVbIF.png)

This is a post that covered the same problem but without a solution:

[Display problem - multiple article HTML tags in same owl-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262301/display-problem-multiple-article-html-tags-in-same-owl-item)

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance!